# Cannot start Guice Repository Injector

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE, Google Guice 3.0, guice-repository 2.1.0, guice-servlet 3.0 and Hibernate 3.

When i installed JpaRepository in servlet module(web.xml), i got the runtime error.

Below is the source code

```
public class JpaGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule(){
            @Override
             protected void configureServlets() {
                this.install(new JpaRepositoryModule("ptol-persistence-unit") {
                    @Override
                    protected void bindRepositories(RepositoryBinder binder) {
                        binder.bind(CategoryRepository.class).to("ptol-persistence-unit");
                    }
                });
                //filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
             }
        });
    }

}
```

In web.xml

```
<!-- Listener Configuration -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>phattuonline.common.base.JpaGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

i got the error:

```
Jul 10, 2013 4:37:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class phattuonline.common.base.JpaGuiceServletConfig
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/transaction/annotation/TransactionAnnotationParser;)V
    at com.google.code.guice.repository.configuration.JpaRepositoryModule.createTransactionAttributeSource(JpaRepositoryModule.java:283)
    at com.google.code.guice.repository.configuration.JpaRepositoryModule.configure(JpaRepositoryModule.java:170)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at phattuonline.common.base.JpaGuiceServletConfig$1.configureServlets(JpaGuiceServletConfig.java:19)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at phattuonline.common.base.JpaGuiceServletConfig.getInjector(JpaGuiceServletConfig.java:16)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Do you know why the error happened? Are there something wrong with transaction?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it is some kind of jar conflict, may be multiple version of jars being used

Comment: I'm using Maven and it automatically resolved all jars conflict. The errors still happen

Answer (score 1):

Guice Repository Module already contains all dependencies to Spring Data module (you don't need to reference Spring on your POM if you are using only Guice as DI framework. Probably, your POM has explicit dependency to another version of those Spring modules, so Guice are trying to read this explicit version that's not supported.

See https://code.google.com/p/guice-repository/wiki/DevGuide?tm=6#Where_i_can_get_it?